# I face below error when run the code : array assignment index out of range

Tags: python, arrays

I try to run this code but one error : array assignment index out of range

```
def amir(st) :
    i = 0
    j = 0
    a = array.array('b')
    while i <= len(st)+1:
        a[i] = model[st[i]]
        i +=1
    return a[i]
```

Comment: The while-condition lets i become "len(st)" and even one more.

Answer (score 0):

- First, it is out of range as when `i` takes value `len(st)` and `len(st)+1`, the index for st will be out of bound.
- `j` is not used in your code.
- You do not really need a loop, it seems that you just want`model[st[-1]]`.

  ```
  def amir(st) :
      return model[st[-1]]
  ```